# Sort Dataframe by Descending Rows AND Columns at the Same Time

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, indexing

> Currently have a dataframe that is countries by series, with values ranging from 0-25
>
> I want to sort the df so that the highest values appear in the top left (first), while the lowest appear in the bottom right (last).

### FROM

```
        A   B   C   D  ...

USA     4   0   10  16
CHN     2   3   13  22
UK      2   1   8   14
...
```

### TO

```
      D   C   A   B   ...

CHN   22  13  2   3
USA   16  10  4   0
UK    14  8   2   1

...
```

In this, the column with the highest values is now first, and the same is true with the index.

> I have considered reindexing, but this loses the 'Countries' Index.

```
    D   C   A   B   ...

0   22  13  2   3
1   16  10  4   0
2   14  8   2   1
...
```

> > I have thought about creating a new column and row that has the Mean or Sum of values for that respective column/row, but is this the most efficient way?
> >
> > > How would I then sort the DF after I have the new rows/columns??

Is there a way to reindex using...

```
df_mv.reindex(df_mv.mean(or sum)().sort_values(ascending = False).index, axis=1)
```

... that would allow me to keep the country index, and simply sort it accordingly?

Thanks for any and all advice or assistance.

> ### EDIT
>
> > Intended result organizes columns AND rows from largest to smallest.
> >
> > > Regarding the first row of the A and B columns in the intended output, these are supposed to be 2, 3 respectively. This is because the intended result interprets the A column as greater than the B column in both sum and mean (even though either sum or mean can be considered for the 'value' of a row/column).

By saying the higher numbers would be in the top left, while the lower ones would be in the bottom right, I simply meant this as a general trend for the resulting df. It is the columns and rows as whole however, that are the intended focus. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Shouldn't you get `3, 2` at the end in the first row in your result?

Comment: Please forgive the ambiguity, thank you all for your answers! Will edit the post to better reflect intended output...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
rows_index=df.max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index
col_index=df.max().sort_values(ascending=False).index
new_df=df.loc[rows_index,col_index]
print(new_df)

      D   C  A  B
CHN  22  13  2  3
USA  16  10  4  0
UK   14   8  2  1
```

Comment: This does not match the expected result.

Comment: His actually does, yours does not. @jorijnsmit

Comment: Look well at the expected result, now that I notice it is your answer that does not match

Comment: I don't understand why you have `2, 3` and not `3, 2` in the first row at the end.

Comment: Hmm question is ambiguous actually. OP asks for highest number in the top left (`22`) and lowest in the bottom right; which is `0`!

Comment: Using df.max unfortunately did not yield the results I was looking for-  however, keeping all else the same and changing that df.max to df.mean, worked out great! thank you!

Comment: I am glad to help you:)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.T` to [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) rows to columns and vice versa:

```
df = df.sort_values(df.max().idxmax(), ascending=False)
df = df.T
df = df.sort_values(df.columns[0], ascending=False).T
```

Result:

```
>>> df
      D   C  B  A
CHN  22  13  3  2
USA  16  10  0  4
UK   14   8  1  2
```

Comment: Why do you know that you must order by D? I think this is not a general solution.

Comment: You are right! Edited my answer to sort by `df.max().idxmax()` instead of by arbitrarily selecting a column with a highest value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `4, 0` in the second  row and `2, 1` in the last row at the end?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ question can be interpreted in multiple ways.

Comment: I think the expected output speaks for itself

Comment: @ansev Ok. If you take the expected output of OP you get `2, 1` in the last row and not `1, 2`.

Comment: which on the other hand is the output that OP expects

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, this time without transposing but using `axis=1` as an argument:

```
df = df.sort_values(df.max().idxmax(), ascending=False)
df = df.sort_values(df.index[0], axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`:

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
arr = arr[np.max(arr, axis=1).argsort()[::-1], :]
arr = np.sort(arr, axis=1)[:, ::-1]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
      A   B  C  D
USA  22  13  3  2
CHN  16  10  4  0
UK   14   8  2  1
```